# ssh daemon and port forwarding issues

Tags: networking, ssh

could somebody please help me? I am trying to troubleshoot a ssh server connection. The daemon runs fine on a local network but for some reason will refuse a external connection even though the port is forwarded to the router. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Service Providers quite often block common ports like 22, 80, and the like.  It's possible that your ISP is blocking that port from incoming connections.  Try forwarding a different WAN port to internal port 22.  i.e., have public port 2222 forward to your PC's port 22.  So in effect, on an external machine you would run:

```
ssh -p 2222 [public_ip]
```

to get access to your machine from the outside.  Just change the incoming port on the router to 2222 or something else (22222 is even less likely to be blocked).